# Im not receiving email after payment completed

Tags: php, html, forms

im new to PHP and HTML, what im doing is basically a form with payment integration using PayPal standard button, what I need is when the customer hit pay and the payment completed to send me an email what he filled in the form, I have tried below code but it seems not working, it takes to pay and when the payment completed it doesn't send any email, these only the codes are included.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Feedback Form</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: helvetica;
        }
        body{
            background-color: #ffd700;
        }
        .main{
            width: 500px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border: 5px solid #dc143c;
            border-left: 40px solid #dc143c;
            box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px #555;
        }
        .info{
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #dc143c;
            padding: 7px;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #222;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        .form-box{
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #eee;
        }
        label{
            color: navy;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        .inp,.msg-box{
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 4px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 2px solid #dc143c;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #dc143c;
            border-right: 15px solid #dc143c;
            border-left: 15px solid #dc143c;
            resize: none;
        }
        .msg-box{
            height: 80px;
        }
        .inp:focus,.msg-box:focus{
            outline: none;
            border: 2px solid navy;
            border-right: 15px solid navy;
            border-left: 15px solid navy;
        }
        .sub-btn{
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            border: none;
            background: linear-gradient(#dc143c,#800000);
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #444;
        }
        .sub-btn:hover{
            background: linear-gradient(#800000,#dc143c);
            opacity: 0.8;
            transition: all ease-out 0.2s;
        }
        .sub-btn:focus{
            outline: none;
        }
        @media(max-width: 720px){
            .main{
                width: 90%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">

    <div class="main">
        <title>Form</title>
        <div class="info">Give Your Feedback!</div>
        <form action="mail_handler.php" method="post" name="form" class="form-box">
            <label for="name">Name</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required><br>
            <label for="email">Email ID</label><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required><br>
            <label for="phone">Phone</label><br>
            <input type="tel" name="phone" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Phone" required><br>
            <label for="message">Message</label><br>
            <textarea name="msg" class="msg-box" placeholder="Enter Your Message Here..." required></textarea><br>


            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXX">
            <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
            </form>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Mail_handler.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $msg=$_POST['msg'];

        $to='n.metanii@gmail.com'; // Receiver Email ID, Replace with your email ID
        $subject='Form Submission';
        $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Phone :".$phone."\n"."Wrote the following :"."\n\n".$msg;
        $headers="From: ".$email;

        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo "<h1>Sent Successfully! Thank you"." ".$name.", We will contact you shortly!</h1>";
        }
        else{
            echo "Something went wrong!";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: It looks you you have a form inside of a form. The form is being submitted to PayPal and not your mail_handler.php file.

Comment: means after payment you ll get a callback from paypal that payment completed that success url you have to set this email sending and give orders something

Answer (score 0):

As @jd182 mentioned you have a form in a form which is improper. Logically you're thinking, hey do both at the same time. However at this point in the code, you are not on PayPal's site yet. What you need is a redirect from PayPal's site to your site when payment is complete, and then you would have some php code to send out the mail.

Check this link for doing the redirect (return url) on your hosted paypal button:

https://www.paypal.com/lc/webapps/mpp/buttons

Now in order to get at those form fields from your return url, research paypal "pass thru" or "custom" fields. Basically how this would work is you would submit those fields you're interested in or temporarily save them to a database (and then submit the row id or other unique id you generate) with your paypal request. Paypal will return your "pass thru" or "custom" fields to your return url. Your email script will then need to be programmed to fetch the row from the database to then know who to send the email to.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't go deep that much-using database and so on, just I want to receive the email what the customer has submitted, its possible also using a callback or redirect URL??

Comment: A database would make the code a bit more complex or deep as you mentioned. An easier (less code) approach would be to save the fields you want retained to `$_SESSION`. Remember, javascript won't be able to get anything into session from the current page. So what you could do (there are many ways, this is just one) is perform an ajax call (synchronous) to another php script that stores the user's email to session. This script could be called on a button that *doesn't* submit the form directly. Instead the button runs the synchronous ajax call and then afterwards thru javascript really submits.

Comment: Or, you could supply the email address as a custom field to your paypal request. You will still need an intermediary button that copies the user's email to the custom field in your form (by way of javascript) before the same script then *really* submits the form.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I got your point, but if you can help me with providing a video explaining what you have said to understand your point more.

Comment: Thats not going to happen with the video @x'DNasoor. I've pointed you to the PayPal API docs on the subject already. All you need to do now is familarize yourself with that on getting the custom field setup and some basic javascript to set the field before the form is submitted.

Comment: I upvoted the answer, but the link you have provided saying "Something’s not right.", can you please provide the correct one.

Comment: Is the date/time on your computer correct? The link works. Maybe you have a browser-related virus. I dunno. But you can (insert search engine here) it on the internet. My original answer has what you'll be looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Code seems okay.

Use a valid e-mail address of the sender, you can bounce back from the receiving mail server.

Don't forget, there are many anti spam technology's. 
Most important is that you respect and know how SPF is working.

> Only domains that are hosted on our servers can be used in 'From' field. Any domain that is not hosted with us cannot be added to 'From' field. We had to take this measure to prevent sending spam using forums, guest books and contact forms scripts. For your site scripts to work properly you should set 'From' field to email account that has been created in your cPanel. Please note that SMTP relaying is not allowed too.